# Angular 6: OnChanges does not work with async pipe

Tags: angular

I have a component that needs to track changes to the data source. The parent component provides data via async pipe. If the data source is changed (item added or deleted), then ngOnChanges does not fires.

Help to deal with the problem.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-todo',
  template: `
<div>
  <button (click)="addTodo()">Add Item</button><br />

    <div *ngFor="let todo of todos">
        {{ todo.value }} <button (click)="deleteTodo(todo.id)">x</button>
    </div>
</div>
`
})
export class TodoComponent implements OnChanges {
  @Input() todos: Todo[];

  constructor(private todoService: TodoService) {
  }

  addTodo() {
    this.todoService.create({ value: 'value '+this.todos.length });
  }

  ngOnChanges(changes: { [key: string]: SimpleChange })
  {
    if (changes['todos']) { 
      console.log('todos changed')
    }
  }

  deleteTodo(todoId: number) {
    this.todoService.remove(todoId);
  }
}
```

Parent component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
<h1>Angular Observable Data Services</h1>

<p>Only implimented a simple post and delete</p>

<h3>Component 1</h3>
<app-todo [todos]='todos | async'></app-todo>

<br /><br />

<h3>Component 2</h3>
<app-todo [todos]='todos | async'></app-todo>
`
})
export class AppComponent  {
  todos: Observable<Todo[]>;

  constructor(private todoService: TodoService){
    this.todos = this.todoService.todos;

    this.todoService.loadAll();
  }
}
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-frl1x5)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're hitting shallow/deep clone problem.

For example, in your service `create` method you copy `this.dataStore` but then you reuse its `todos` property which is not copied, it stays the same reference thus there is nothing to trigger `onChange`.

what you want to do is something like:

```
this.dataStore.todos.push(something); //this mutates an array
const x = [...this.dataStore.todos];`//clones actual array
```

and feed that into your `BehaviorSubject.next(x)`

useful ref:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign#Deep_Clone